# replace using regex in Dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

Input

```
$filter=FirstName eq 'LISA'&$select=Id,CoveredSkus,FirstName&
```

My Script to remove the "select" query param

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
payload replace "\$select=.*?(&|\$)"  with ""
```

Expected Output

```
$filter=FirstName eq 'LISA'&
```

Actual Output

```
$filter=FirstName eq 'LISA'&$select=Id,CoveredSkus,FirstName&
```

What am I doing wrong here ? I do see this regex works in matching the correct substring as shown here - https://regex101.com/r/2RZoPX/1

If there is another way to remove the "select" data, I am open to that aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is correct, you are just using the wrong way to use regex in replace. Regex needs to be enclosed in '//' instead of "".
Try like this for regex:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload replace /\$select=.*?(&|\$)/  with ""
```

Alternate way with SubstringBefore:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Strings
---
payload substringBefore('\$select')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var inp = "\$filter=FirstName eq 'LISA'&\$select=Id,CoveredSkus,FirstName&"
---
(inp splitBy("&"))[0] ++ "&"
```